# TCP IP Connection Problem with Unity from Android Phone to PC

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, tcp, connection, ip

I have created a simple application with Unity that contains a button and an InputField, this application uses TCP Connection, sends a string that is written in the inputbox to the C# console application that runs as the Server.

Everything works perfectly when I use both applications on the same PC, but when I install the apk file on my phone it does not work. Both PC and Phone are connected to the same router, and I also turned the firewall off.
This is not my first time using Unity or tcp connection on a C# application but it is my first time using them together.
Is there anyone had the same issue? And how did you solve it?
I appreciate any help. Thanks to everyone from now!

the application looks like this [App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkn3m.png)

Client Script on Unity

```
            
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;
public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TcpClient tcpClient;

    public async Task Initialize(string ip, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (tcpClient.Connected)
            tcpClient.Close();
    }

    public bool Connected()
    {
        if (tcpClient != null)
            if (tcpClient.Connected)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public async Task Read()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        while (true)
        {
            var bytesRead = await ns.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead <= 0) break; // Stream was closed
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        Debug.Log("connection closed");
    }


    public void BeginSend(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg + "\n");
            var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            ns.BeginWrite(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, EndSend, bytes);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void EndSend(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var bytes = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
    }
}
```

TCP Server C# Console Application -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;


public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TcpClient tcpClient;

    public async Task Initialize(string ip, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (tcpClient.Connected)
            tcpClient.Close();
    }

    public bool Connected()
    {
        if (tcpClient != null)
            if (tcpClient.Connected)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public async Task Read()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        while (true)
        {
            var bytesRead = await ns.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead <= 0) break; // Stream was closed
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
        Debug.Log("connection closed");
    }


    public void BeginSend(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg + "\n");
            var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
            ns.BeginWrite(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, EndSend, bytes);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void EndSend(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var bytes = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
    }
}
```

And the UIController script that controls UI and TCP Connection

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;




public class UIControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    //objects
    public Text textDeneme;

    private static byte[] MessageToByteArray(string message, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var byteCount = encoding.GetByteCount(message);
        if (byteCount > byte.MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentException("Message size is greater than 255 bytes in the provided encoding");
        var byteArray = new byte[byteCount + 1];
        byteArray[0] = (byte)byteCount;
        encoding.GetBytes(message, 0, message.Length, byteArray, 1);
        return byteArray;
    }

    
    public void connectBtn()
    {

        string message = textDeneme.text;
        var byteArray = MessageToByteArray(message, Encoding.ASCII);
        using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {
            tcpClient.Connect("192.168.1.133", 5000);
            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(networkStream))
            {
                bufferedStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I had problems with the text editor. Arranged and added codes now.

Comment: `Initialize(string ip, int port)` We cannot see which ip you used and you did not tell. And where is this function called?

Comment: it calls it from connectBtn() function.

Comment: Initialize()? Dont see that. Anyhow you will have a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Have a look at the logs.